# MongoDB Compass use SSL with .pem File

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-compass

I'm trying to connect (SSL) to `MongoDB` using `Compass` with this connection string - it's using a .pem file.  It doesn't work (timeout) and will not save my changes - wierd.  I think I need to add "Server Validation" somewhere.

> `mongodb://sys-asdasd:jruj2mf6nsmx10jf@lxv5656.asdas.com:27010,lxv5657.asdasd.com:27010/ABUsers?authMechanism=PLAIN&replicaSet=MPODS-DEV-002&connectTimeoutMS=10000&socketTimeoutMS=5000&readPreference=primary&authSource=%24external&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&authSource=$external&ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=C:\Certs\CAAries.pem`

Answer (score 0):

Consult the server error log, it will say why connections are not being accepted.